# Events and Delegates in c# : How to use Events & Delegates to Notify One class about changes in other class

Tags: c#, winforms, console

The question is below the proper way to use Events & Delegates to call method of class `A:Show1()` using event of class B which is raised in `B:Show()`

```
public class classA
{
    private classB _Thrower;

    public classA()
    {
        _Thrower = new classB();            
        _Thrower.ThrowEvent += (sender, args) => { show1(); };
    }

    public void show1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class 2");
    }
}

public class classB
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);

    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent = delegate { };
    public classB()
    {
        this.ThrowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class 1");            
    }
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes in question this is my first time of stackoverflow

Comment: 1) Exceptions are thrown and events are RAISED. 2) You want to call a method declared in A from a method declared in B without using Type A?

Comment: If you want to invoke a method of a class it must either be static or you have to create an instance of that class before. Even your code above creates an instance of classB in `_Thrower = new classB();`.
Sorry, I do not yet understand what you're trying to do with this event raising stuff.
Maybe you want to create an anonymous instance like `new classB().show()`?

Comment: pleas see my edit thanks

Comment: yes @NoëlWidmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant think of what you are trying to accomplish, but to answer your question this might do it. Unless I did not understand your question right.
Mind you that this violates a principle of OOP that states that each class should be independant of other classes.

```
public class classA
{
    public void show1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am class A");
    }
}

public class classB
{
    public void show()
    {
        new classA().show1(); 
        Console.WriteLine("I am class B");            
    }
}
```

Comment: without using any of class a refrence not event instance just through events and delegates

Comment: So you want to call a method from a class without creating that class ? That is impossible.

Comment: defining class is out of question we should define both class just call two methods on call of single method and calling of second method should be done without any use of classA means fire an event to call method of other class

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here ? It makes no sense to me. How can you call a method from something you cannot define ? Events wont help here because events also need an instance to subscribe to. Maybe it helps if you explain why you need this

Comment: The question is if there is class A:show1() and there is class B:show() I have to call show1() in class B without using class A object using delegates and events sorry for your inconvenience

Comment: Without using an instance of classA it is impossible to call a method from it. It does not matter if you want to use delegates and events, even they need an instance.

Comment: Check My Comment Sir

Answer (score 1):

To get the result from your edited question you can use this code:

```
static void Main()
{
    classA obA = new classA();
    classB obB = new classB();
    obA.Shown += ( object sender, EventArgs e ) => { obB.ShowB(); };
    obA.ShowA();
}

public class classA
{
    public event EventHandler Shown;

    public classA()
    {
    }

    public void ShowA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "I am class A" );

        if( Shown != null )
            Shown( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }
}

public class classB
{
    public event EventHandler Shown;

    public classB()
    {
    }

    public void ShowB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "I am class B" );

        if( Shown != null )
            Shown( this, EventArgs.Empty );
    }
}
```

In `main()` method you could do it vica versa as well:

```
obB.Shown += ( object sender, EventArgs e ) => { obA.ShowA(); };
obB.ShowB();
```

But you should not do both at the same time or you'll get an infinite loop ending up in a stackoverflow

Comment: Man Please See My Answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess This is the answer @GuidoG @Kai Thoma

```
class A
{
    public A(B b)
    {
        b.ShowA += new methcall(this.showA);
    }
    public void showA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Class A");
    }
}
class B
{
    public event methcall ShowA;
    public void showB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Class B");
        if (ShowA != null)
            ShowA();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A(b);
        methcall m = new methcall(b.showB);
        m.Invoke();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```